# Show that the interior is not empty in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology

Show that the interior of the set $M= \{ x \in \mathbb R^3:a_i^tx \le b_i , i=1,...,m\} $, where $a_i$ - vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, $b_i$ - positive numbers is not empty.

I wanted to take a sphere in the centre in point $x \in M$ with radius small enough that every other point in $S$ will be also in $M$. But I'm not sure how to show it, I was thinking about taking the radius $\frac{b_i-a_i^tx}{\lVert a_i \rVert}$, but I can't get any conclusion with that. Can someone help me?

Comment: $ \{ x \in \mathbb R^3:a_i^tx < b_i , i=1,...,m\} $ is the inverse image of an open set under a  continuous function, so it is open.

Comment: What does $a_i^tx$ mean?

Comment: @AdamRubinson it's the matrix multiplication form of the dot product.

Comment: You mean like ${a_i}^T a_i$ ?

Comment: @geetha290krm Correct, but may be empty.

Comment: @geetha290krm My first comment was nonsense. Your hint was essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geetha290krm gave the crucial hint:

The function $f_i : \mathbb  R^3 \to \mathbb R, f_i(x) =a_i^tx$, is continuous, thus $U_i = f_i^{-1}((-\infty,b_i)) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid a_i^tx < b_i\}$ is open in $\mathbb R^3$. Thus $U = \bigcap_{i=1}^m U_i$ is open and contained in $M$. Since $b_i > 0 = f_i(0)$, we have $0 \in U \subset M$.

Thus the interior of $M$ is not empty.

Comment: Wait, but how did you get that $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$? We have that $x_1+x_2+x_3 \le 1$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3 \ge -1$

Comment: @delta Oops, you are right. My answer was nonsense. I have rewritten it.